# Link CSS and Images to Spring MVC maven Projcet

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a Spring project created using maven. The following is my directory structure.

[image]

I want to add css images to this project. For this, i created a resources folder inside the web-inf directory and placed an image there. To my dispatcher servlet xml, i added 3 lines, pertaining to mvc. One line is in the xmlns:mvc and the other 2 are the last 2 lines in the schema location:

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

The mvc xmlns and xsi locations were not present earlier, i added them so that the following line works:

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/**" mapping="/resources"/>
```

When i add the above 3 lines, My project does not work. I get the error:

```
description The requested resource is not available.
```

If i remove the mvc lines from the beans declaration and run the project w/o images/css the project runs.

Can anyone help me with this? If the above method is not the way to add css and images to a spring mvc project, please point out to the correct way.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a small change viz.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

plus according to standard maven project create a new folder and put your resources in this

```
src/main/resources
```

Comment: Hi Kalher I get the following error on making the above change cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'resources'. One of '{"http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, 
 "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/
 schema/beans"]}' is expected.

Comment: Make sure you also have declared `<mvc:annotation-driven />` element.

Comment: The *classpath* part of this answer is nonsense. Resources might be standard web application resources (/src/main/webapp/**). Please remove it or write it in a way so that it does not suggest that having resources on classpath is necessary.

Comment: This is one solution, of course it is not necessary to put resources in class path.

Answer (score 0):

```
   webapp/resources/css 
   <head>
  <link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/commoncss.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
```

if not looking resources folder in webapp then manually create folder as resources/css folder inside webapp put your css file inside css folder.